# How to generate the newid when there is change in column value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider below example

```
ID| RecordUID                          |   Person |Value
1 |49D62793-989B-4135-9873-21572D511297|   Test   |10
2 |49D62793-989B-4135-9873-21572D511297|   Test   |11
3 |DDB40B89-2BB4-4536-9847-32B9F53C0196|   Test1  |21
```

how to generate the above new id(RecordUID(NewID())) when there is a change in the value of a person column?

I need for a select query like

```
Select ID,NewID() when a change in Person, value from Table A
```

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: What's wrong with your select? Are you looking for triggers?

Comment: you should use a timestamp column, update is automatic

Comment: @Esperento57 OP needs to update `RecordUID` column **ONLY IF** `Person` column updated. Thus this won't help.

Comment: use trigger then like propose Sami

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for an `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER` as the following

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrig
ON Data
AFTER UPDATE
AS

   UPDATE D
   SET RecordUID = NEWID()
   FROM Data D 
   JOIN (
          SELECT I.Id
          FROM INSERTED I
          JOIN DELETED D ON I.Id = D.Id AND I.Person <> D.Person
        ) T ON D.Id = T.Id;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4aff269c9407732804256c27eb9afb4) where you can see how it's working online.

Comment: Im looking for View in SQL server

Comment: You can't do tthat in a `VIEW`. How would you detect if `Person` value changed?